# intel centrino 6250 agn not loading wlan interface

Tags: networking, wifi, network-interface, networkmanager

I bought this PCI card: [Intel Centrino WiMAX 6250](https://ark.intel.com/products/59468/Intel-Centrino-Advanced-N--WiMAX-6250-Dual-Band).

**Problem:**

The wifi card is detected by the system, it loads the module, etc but does not create the interface.

```
ifconfig

enp3s0f2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.200  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::4c0a:d5e6:142:f61a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:90:f5:d9:7b:ee  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 294  bytes 116769 (116.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 344  bytes 34308 (34.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 342  bytes 25060 (25.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 342  bytes 25060 (25.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

but

```
sudo lspci

02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N + WiMAX 6250 [Kilmer Peak] (rev 5e)
```

Originally the 6250 card loaded the `RTL818X_PCI` module, I followed up by replacing it with the `iwldvm` module which I got for the [wlwifi-6050-ucode](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi) firmware, this can apparently be used for the 6250 card.

Regarding the issue of blacklisted hardware, I spoke to a technician from the supplier (Mecer) and paraphrasing what he said - if I can fit it in, it should work - referring to the pci wifi card

Here you can see the wifi card is installed:

```
sudo lshw

*-pci:1
     description: PCI bridge
     product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 1c.2
     bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.2
     version: c4
     width: 32 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
     configuration: driver=pcieport
     resources: irq:18 memory:f7b00000-f7bfffff
   *-network DISABLED
        description: Wireless interface
        product: Centrino Advanced-N + WiMAX 6250 [Kilmer Peak]
        vendor: Intel Corporation
        physical id: 0
        bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
        logical name: wlp2s0
        version: 5e
        serial: fa:bb:b7:25:93:6d
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
        configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.10.0-14-generic firmware=41.28.5.1 build 33926 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
        resources: irq:31 memory:f7b00000-f7b01fff
```

**Log:**

[full iwlwifi errors](https://pastebin.com/kCRnwUFB)

**a few of the log errors**

```
Apr  3 02:07:32 cybex-W55xEU kernel: [  753.517987] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:2779096482:0xa5a5a5a2:2779096482
Apr  3 02:07:32 cybex-W55xEU kernel: [  753.518024] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Error -110 on calib cmd 15
Apr  3 02:07:32 cybex-W55xEU kernel: [  753.518026] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Could not complete ALIVE transition: -110
Apr  3 02:07:32 cybex-W55xEU kernel: [  753.541115] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 8 [0xa5a5a5a2]
Apr  3 02:07:32 cybex-W55xEU wpa_supplicant[1105]: Could not set interface wlp2s0 flags (UP): Connection timed out
Apr  3 02:07:32 cybex-W55xEU kernel: [  753.545377] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
Apr  3 02:07:32 cybex-W55xEU kernel: [  753.545384] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
Apr  3 02:07:32 cybex-W55xEU kernel: [  753.545432] ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
Apr  3 02:07:32 cybex-W55xEU wpa_supplicant[1105]: WEXT: Could not set interface 'wlp2s0' UP
Apr  3 02:07:32 cybex-W55xEU NetworkManager[924]: <error> [1491178052.1546] sup-iface[0x5653b33feed0,wlp2s0]: error adding interface: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interface.
Apr  3 02:07:32 cybex-W55xEU wpa_supplicant[1105]: wlp2s0: Failed to initialize driver interface
Apr  3 02:07:32 cybex-W55xEU NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1491178052.1547] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: starting -> down
Apr  3 02:07:33 cybex-W55xEU kernel: [  754.977899] usb 3-4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Apr  3 02:07:37 cybex-W55xEU kernel: [  758.467371] i2400m_usb 3-4:1.0: untested minor fw version 9.3.2
Apr  3 02:07:37 cybex-W55xEU kernel: [  758.467372] i2400m_usb 3-4:1.0: firmware interface version 9.3.2
Apr  3 02:07:41 cybex-W55xEU NetworkManager[924]: <warn>  [1491178061.9847] device (wlp2s0): re-acquiring supplicant interface (#5).
Apr  3 02:07:41 cybex-W55xEU kernel: [  763.379440] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
Apr  3 02:07:41 cybex-W55xEU kernel: [  763.379607] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
Apr  3 02:07:41 cybex-W55xEU kernel: [  763.379693] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
Apr  3 02:07:42 cybex-W55xEU kernel: [  763.413299] i2400m_usb 3-4:1.0: notification: URB error -71, retrying
Apr  3 02:07:42 cybex-W55xEU kernel: [  763.419289] i2400m_usb 3-4:1.0: notification: URB error -71, retrying
```

I saw this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/422936/intel-centrino-wimax-6250-constant-slow-and-dropped-signal-ubuntu-13-10), it is not relevant since I cannot even scan

Also, please note. I have a hardware switch, using `Fn` + `F11` which switches my wifi on and off. When the wifi of the laptop is on, an led should be on solid green, but with this wifi card, no light ever comes on for the wifi.

Does this imply some sort of blacklisted hardware/incompatibility?

Thanks